# Connect Ethernet and WiFi networks together in the same computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, debian, ics

I have a wifi home network, And a laptop "D", that doesn't have wifi connectivity. I can plug it in to "W", one of wifi enabled computers via an Ethernet cable and now it's possible to get Internet connectivity using Windows Internet connection Sharing Service.

But according to my knowledge, the main wireless router doesn't know that this D's existence. Right?

In D, the OS is Debian and I added a route through W's Ethernet network IP. Then D can connect to other computers in the wifi network.

My problem is that how do I let other computers in the wifi network to connect to D? Is that possible?

I tried to add a route to the W's Ethernet IP in router's routing table. But its not reachable of cause.

Comment: Your question is very confusing.

Comment: @Ramhound : oh sorry my English is bit slow.

Comment: There maybe a very clunky method to get traffic to flow to that Debian machine via ICS but it would be very 'botched'. I would recommend just going and buying a WiFi Dongle for Laptop D.

Comment: @CharlesH : Thanks for the suggestion. Any temporary suggestions, however ?

Comment: @shan well you are on the right path really. Any PC going to another on the network will query its Gateway (WiFi Router I guess in your situation). The route on the Laptop W will work however nothing is getting there yet so you need a route at the Gateway level as well. Depending on what device your WiFi router is you should be able to add a route to push the traffic to Laptop W which will then pick it up and use its route to push the traffic to Laptop D... make sense?

Comment: @CharlesH : It's a ZTE w300 wifi router. Ok, I can add routes to its routing table pointing which? How can the W computer get the traffic from the router and point it to the Ethernet network? That part confusing.

Comment: @shan The ZTE w300 has its IP address. Laptop W with two IP addresses one for WiFi and One for Ethernet. Laptop D with one IP address for Ethernet. The static route on the ZTE w300 should say "Route Laptop-D-Ehternet-IP Mask x.x.x.x Laptop-W-WiFi-IP" which will push traffic from Router to Laptop W when it gets a request for Laptop D. Now when this traffic hits Laptop W it needs another route to say "Route Laptop-D-Ehternet-IP Mask x.x.x.x Laptop-W-Ethernet-IP" this basically says you want Laptop D you can find him down that Ethernet Cable. One issue you will have is DNS so test with IP.

Comment: @CharlesH : wow great. I got it. Thank you very much. Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: @sean great stuff, glad this is working for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as above in the comments all relates to correct routing of the traffic.

The ZTE w300 has its IP address. 
Laptop W with two IP addresses one for WiFi and One for Ethernet. 
Laptop D with one IP address for Ethernet.

The static route on the ZTE w300 should state "Route Laptop-D-Ehternet-IP Mask x.x.x.x Laptop-W-WiFi-IP" which will push traffic from Router to Laptop W when it gets a request for Laptop D.

Now when this traffic hits Laptop W it needs another route to say "Route Laptop-D-Ehternet-IP Mask x.x.x.x Laptop-W-Ethernet-IP" this basically says you want Laptop D you can find him down that Ethernet Cable. One issue you will have is DNS so test with IP.